# False positive with Rspec's "expect to receive"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've realized that the way I've been writing tests is producing false positives.

Say I have this source code

```
class MyClass
  def foo
  end
  def bar
    1
  end
end
```

The `foo` method does nothing, but say I want to write a test that makes sure it calls `bar` under the hood (even though it doesn't). Furthermore, I want to ensure that the result of calling `bar` directly is `1`.

```
it "test" do
  inst = MyClass.new
  expect(inst).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
  inst.foo
  expect(inst.bar).to eq(1)
end
```

So this is returning true, but I want it to return false.

I want this line:

```
  expect(inst).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
```

to **not** take into account the fact that **in my test case** I'm calling `inst.bar` directly. I want it to **only** look at the internal of the `foo` method.

Comment: why so complicated? `expect(inst.bar).to eq(1)` is simply enough.

Comment: You'll have to move the second `expect` to another test example.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it's an example to show a concept, it's not literally the code I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'r defining 2 separate test cases within one test case. You should change it to 2 separate tests.

```
describe '#bar' do
  it "uses #foo" do
    inst = MyClass.new
    allow(inst).to receive(:foo).and_call_original
    inst.bar
    expect(inst).to have_received(:foo)
  end

  it "returns 1" do
    inst = MyClass.new
    # if you don't need to mock it, don't do it
    # allow(inst).to receive(:foo).and_call_original
    expect(inst.bar).to eq(1)
  end

  # if you really, really wan't to do it your way, you can specify the amount of calls
  it "test" do
    inst = MyClass.new
    allow(inst).to receive(:foo).and_call_original
    inst.foo
    expect(inst.bar).to eq(1)
    expect(inst).to have_received(:foo).twice # or replace .twice with .at_least(2).times
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, this is what I ended up doing in the meantime before I saw any answers. Thanks for pitching in. I'll leave this open for a day or two and if there's no better answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: `allow.to receive` followed later by `expect.to have_received` is a bit redundant, isn't it? Forget the `have_received` line and change `allow` to `expect`.

Comment: ... unless, I suppose, you're in the middle of an example and want to specify *where* that method should be received.

Comment: No. It's not redundant.  Allow prepares a mock. It can receive the call and it can not. Later with expect I check if it did happen. This way you can prepare the scene and set the expect call at the end. Your way the expect is scattered within the test. I think it is the cleaner syntax to have expect at the end of your test. This way you have always to look at the end of a spec to know what is tested.

Answer (score 1):

Stubs are typically used in two ways:

1. Check if the method was called i.e. `expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:foo)` in this case what it returns is not really imortant
2. To simulate behaviour `allow_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:method).and_return(fake_response)`. This is a great way to avoid database interactions and or isolate out other dependencies in tests.

For example in a test that requires data setup of a Rails ActiveRecord model `Product` that has a has many association `comments`:

```
let(:product) { Product.new }
let(:comments) { [Comment.new(text: "Foo"), Comment.new(text: "Bar")] }

before :each do
  allow_any_instnace_of(Product).to recieve(:comments).and_return(comments)
```

Now in any of your `it` blocks when you call `product.comments` you will get back an array of comments you can use in the tests without having gone near your database which makes the test orders of magnitudes faster.

When you are using the stub to check if the method was called the key is to declare the expectation before you perform the opreation that calls the method. For example:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to recieve(:bar).exactly(1).times.with('hello')
Foo.new.bar('hello') # will return true
```

Comment: note I'm using any_instance_of because I think its a more robust option to use in tests, you don't have to use it. It really depends on the situation